# BeanShell: String + function's value

Tags: java, jmeter, beanshell

Who can help me?

BeanShell:

- Works:

  ```
  ${__setProperty(MyProperty, ${__UUID()})};
  ```

  Result: `3d63d204-ce35-4c82-9ac6-4479197f76c0`
- Doesn't work:

  ```
  ${__setProperty(MyProperty, ${__UUID()}+"Test")};
  ```

  Result: `+Test`

  Expectations: `3d63d204-ce35-4c82-9ac6-4479197f76c0Test`

Oleg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BeanShell, it's easier to do this:

```
props.put("MyProperty", UUID.randomUUID().toString() + "Test");
```

In your previous syntax though, don't add `+`, and it should work too:

```
${__setProperty(MyProperty, ${__UUID()}Test)};
```

Otherwise, please show us which elemnt do you use to set it.